# cmd pipe -> System cannot find specified path

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, pipe

Using `cmd` on Windows 10 Pro 21H2, when I try

```
echo Hello | find "Bye"
```

I get `The system cannot find the specified path`. Same thing if trying

```
echo Hello | C:\Windows\System32\find.exe "Bye"
```

So `PATH` does not appear to be the problem.

I need this working because of how Visual Studio Code connects to ssh servers:

```
type "C:\Users\thomedes\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-vpc-13769646.sh" | ssh -T -D 64480 server bash
```

which gives exactly the same issue.

EDIT:

Just tried on an old machine with Windows XP. Works flawlessly.

EDIT:

System info. It's in Spanish, but should be easy to understand. I'ts a normal Windows 10 installation. No magic tricks.

```
C:\Users\thomedes>dir echo*
El volumen de la unidad C es Windows
El número de serie del volumen es: XXXX-XXXX

Directorio de C:\Users\thomedes

No se encuentra el archivo

C:\Users\thomedes>dir find*
El volumen de la unidad C es Windows
El número de serie del volumen es: XXXX-XXXX

Directorio de C:\Users\thomedes

No se encuentra el archivo

C:\Users\thomedes>where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe

C:\Users\thomedes>where echo
INFORMACIÓN: no se pudo encontrar ningún archivo para los patrones dados.
```

Some more info, it runs fine when done like this:

```
C:\Users\thomedes>echo Hello > foo
C:\Users\thomedes>find "Bye" < foo
```

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share `dir echo*`, `dir find*`, `where find` and `where echo`.

Comment: @JosefZ Done. It'a a plain windows 10 installation. echo is CMD's internal echo command. find is Windows' "grep".

Comment: Could not recreate the problem -- P:\>echo hello | find "hello"
hello

Comment: you should consider that find is by default cade sensitive, you may use `echo HeLlo | findstr /i "hello"

Comment: @Duston Can you please share the -exact- version of Windows you are using? 20H2? 21H1? 21H2? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @djsomi, the problem is not about the find command. It's about cmd failing when I use a pipe ( | ).

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Enterprise] 21H1 [Version 10.0.19043.1526]

Comment: @Duston Thanks. As I thought, apparently, 21H2 has broken the pipe in CMD. Will try to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself because the problem is gone after a Windows Update.

Thanks Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

Always use `findstr` (windows's grep alternative) when grepping in pipes. `find` does other stuff, too.

This will work on any Windows version:

```
echo Hello | findstr "Bye"
```

Comment: Thanks @bjoster, but the problem was not about using find. The issue was about using pipes with a CMD internal command.